# subsetting by index in R

Tags: r, list, indexing, data.table, subset

I have an vector with indexes:

```
indexes
[1] 25  2 16 23
```

and another vector with logical:

```
logical 
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[19] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

i want to keep all logical items that, except those with indexes stored in `indexes`.

i thought this would have an easy solution, but mine doesn't work:

```
  for(index in indexes){
    logical[index] = NULL
  }
```

Comment: Try `logicals[setdiff(1:length(logical),indexes)]`. You take all the indices `1:length(logical)` and remove the unwanted ones.

Comment: Or `logicals[-indexes]`

Answer (score 1):

You could just use minus (`-`) indexing :

```r
indexes <- c(25,  2, 16, 23)
logicals <- sample(c(T,F),25,replace=T)
logicals
#>  [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#> [13] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [25] FALSE
logicals[-indexes]
#>  [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#> [13] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```